# facebook like and share button not working in drupal7

Tags: php, facebook, drupal-7

i try to implement the facebook share and like button into my website in drupal..but its not getting buttons from the facebook..it just displaying the code what i put inthe module..thanks in advance..

```
   facebook.module


   <?php
   function facebook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode)
    {
     $node->content['facebook'] = array(
     '#markup' => theme('facebook_add_like_button'),
     );
    }

     function facebook_theme()
      {
        return array(
        'facebook_add_like_button' => array('variables' => NULL),
        );
        }

         function theme_facebook_add_like_button()
       {
         $output ='&lt;div id="fb-root"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;script src =    "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=657379467662635"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" layout="standard"      action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"&gt;&lt;/fb:like&gt;';
                 return $output;
              }


     This is the code i get from facebook developer

            <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=657379467662635";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


         <fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"    layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you output html entities (like "&lt;") in your theme function instead of actual HTML code.
Replace everything in the "$output" variable with the code you got from facebook developer like this :

```
$output ='<div id ... share="true"></fb:like>';
```

instead of

```
$output ='&lt;div id= ... share="true"&gt;&lt;/fb:like&gt;';
```